# C# Send both HTML and Text email - most elegant?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

Is it best practice to send both HTML and Text email?

If I only send HTML what are the dangers?

I'm thinking something like this below, from http://johnnycoder.com/blog/2009/04/15/net-mailmessage-linkedresources-alternateviews-and-exceptions/.

```
try
{
    // Assign a sender, recipient and subject to new mail message
    MailAddress sender =
        new MailAddress("sender@johnnycoder.com", "Sender");

    MailAddress recipient =
        new MailAddress("recipient@johnnycoder.com", "Recipient");

    MailMessage m = new MailMessage(sender, recipient);
    m.Subject = "Test Message";

    // Define the plain text alternate view and add to message
    string plainTextBody =
        "You must use an email client that supports HTML messages";

    AlternateView plainTextView =
        AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(
            plainTextBody, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);

    m.AlternateViews.Add(plainTextView);

    // Define the html alternate view with embedded image and
    // add to message. To reference images attached as linked
    // resources from your HTML message body, use "cid:contentID"
    // in the <img> tag...
    string htmlBody =
        "<html><body><h1>Picture</h1><br>" +
        "<img src=\"cid:SampleImage\"></body></html>";

    AlternateView htmlView =
        AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(
            htmlBody, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

    // ...and then define the actual LinkedResource matching the
    // ContentID property as found in the image tag. In this case,
    // the HTML message includes the tag
    // <img src=\"cid:SampleImage\"> and the following
    // LinkedResource.ContentId is set to "SampleImage"
    LinkedResource sampleImage =
        new LinkedResource("sample.jpg",
            MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
    sampleImage.ContentId = "SampleImage";

    htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(sampleImage);

    m.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

    // Finally, configure smtp or alternatively use the
    // system.net mailSettings
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
          {
              Host = "smtp.example.com",
              UseDefaultCredentials = false,
              Credentials =
                  new NetworkCredential("username", "password")
          };

    //<system.net>
    //    <mailSettings>
    //        <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
    //            <network host="smtp.example.com"
    //              port="25" defaultCredentials="true"/>
    //        </smtp>
    //    </mailSettings>
    //</system.net>

    smtp.Send(m);
}
catch (ArgumentException)
{
    throw new
        ArgumentException("Undefined sender and/or recipient.");
}
catch (FormatException)
{
    throw new
        FormatException("Invalid sender and/or recipient.");
}
catch (InvalidOperationException)
{
    throw new
        InvalidOperationException("Undefined SMTP server.");
}
catch (SmtpFailedRecipientException)
{
    throw new SmtpFailedRecipientException(
        "The mail server says that there is no mailbox for recipient");
}
catch (SmtpException ex)
{
    // Invalid hostnames result in a WebException InnerException that
    // provides a more descriptive error, so get the base exception
    Exception inner = ex.GetBaseException();
    throw new SmtpException("Could not send message: " + inner.Message);
}
```

Comment: One thing about your plain content, is what I would think if I received a mail from someone that said "you  must use an email client that supports HTML messages". I can't detail what I would think if some stranger told me what software I should be running, because I don't know the stackoverflow policy on profanity, but it wouldn't be conducive to my continued custom.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would say that, in today's world, the "best-practice" approach would be to ensure that you send your message as **both** plain text and HTML (if you really want to send HTML email messages).

Oh, and make sure you do actually send the *content* in the plain text view, rather than a single sentence saying "You must use an email client that supports HTML messages".  Google Mail takes this approach, and it seems to work perfectly, allowing "rich" views on full-fledged PC clients, whilst also allowing "minimal" views on more restricted devices (i.e. Mobile/Cell phones).

If you want to take a purist's view, you wouldn't be sending HTML emails at all, nor would you ever "attach" a binary file to an email.  Both corruptions of the original email standard, which was only ever *originally* intended for plain text.
(See some people's opinions of this [here](http://www.georgedillon.com/web/html_email_is_evil.shtml) and [here](http://birdhouse.org/etc/evilmail.html))

However, in the pragmatic modern-day real world, HTML email is very real, and very acceptable.  The primary downside to sending HTML email is whether the recipient will see the email in the way that you intended them to see it.  This is much the same problem that web designers have battled with for years; getting their websites to look "just right" in all possible browsers (although it's significantly easier today than it was many years ago).

Similar to ensuring that a website functions correctly *without requiring* Javascript, by sending your emails as both HTML and Plain Text, you'll ensure that your emails **degrade gracefully** so that people reading their emails on (for example) small mobile devices (something that's becoming more and more prevalent these days - and which may or may not be capable of rendering a complete HTML email) can still read your email content without issue.

Comment: Many thanks to everyone who has answered - appreciated!  And thanks for keeping to profanity down Jon :-)

Comment: For future finders:  RFC 822 and 2822 dictate that the standard is to use text or (text and html), but not just html.  Proper netiquette is to send plain text e-mail (google netiquette for reference).

Answer (score 4):

If you only send HTML, then anyone reading email on a text-only device will have trouble.

For example, I suspect many low-end mobile devices are capable of reading email but not displaying full HTML.

I would say it's best practice to *either* send text-only, or text and HTML.

I don't see why you're catching a bunch of exceptions only to rethrow the same exception type with a different message, by the way - the original message may well be more descriptive.

Comment: Re catching exceptions and throwing new ones - Not to mention that the stacktrace is being demolished reducing "debugability". If anything the caught exception should be rethrown.

Answer (score 3):

I think yes, the best practice is to send both. The reason (c&p from wikipedia):

> The default e-mail format according to RFC 2822  is plain text. Thus
>   e-mail software isn't required to support HTML formatting. Sending
>   HTML formatted e-mails can therefore lead to problems at the
>   recipient's end if it's one of those clients that don't support it. In
>   the worst case, the recipient will see the HTML code instead of the
>   intended message.

Answer (score 3):

Another reason to send both is that many mailservers mark emails that only contain HTML content as spam. You don't want all your emails to be put in the junk folder.

Comment: Source on the info? (no rudeness intended here)

Comment: I know this is really old but I would trust Mail Chimp as a trusted source: [Spam-filters](http://templates.mailchimp.com/concepts/spam-filters/)  Scroll all of the way to the bottom. Last bullet point: **"Don’t send the HTML email by itself. Always include that plain-text alternative message."**

Answer (score 2):

Sharing my experience with sending both HTML and text in one email:
I have created an email message that has 2 views: text and html using C# AlternateView classes.

What did I get?

**On Mac, tested on High Sierra:**
Apple Mail app was showing the Html. If the order of messages is reversed: Html - text then Apple Mail will show the text view. The conclusion: Apple Mail is using the last view as default.

**In Windows, Outlook 2010:**
Microsoft Outlook by default is using the Html view. The order of views in the email doesn't matter: html,text; text,html;

If for some reason you selected a setting to show incoming messages as a text then the Html version of your email will be converted into the text by Outlook.
Even so you send the text version of your email (which might be slightly different from the HTML version and was formatted to look pretty) it won't be used.

So you don't need to send the text version of your email if you know that your clients use Outlook and Html version is selected as default.

**Mozilla Thunderbird** respects your settings and shows the correct Html or text version of your email. It works correctly on Mac and in Windows

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Several email clients will use the last AlternateView that was added to the AlternateViews.

So if you prefer to have your mail displayed as HTML, be sure to add that last.

I have notice this for IOS mail and OSX mail, while Android Email seems to prefer HTML if it is available. I am not sure for which versions this holds, and the behaviour is often user-configurable, but in my experience these were the defaults.