# Mail sent in spam

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, web-services, email

I have made asp.net webservice in C# to send mail on given mailid as parameter.

Mail is sent but it is shown as spam, not as an inbox mail.

I have used following code;

**.NET CODE :**

```
public int SendMail(string mailto, string username, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            string mailFrom = "test@gmail.com";
            string siteName = "www.XYZ.com";
            MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(mailFrom, siteName);
            SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient();

            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            message.From = fromAddress;
            message.To.Add(mailto);

            message.Subject = "Your User Name and Password";
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;

            mailClient.Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
            mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            mailClient.EnableSsl = false;

            string body = "<HTML><BODY><CENTER><H2>Your User Name  :'" + username + "' </H2><BR/><H2>Your Password :'" + password + "' </H2></CENTER></BODY></HTML>";

            message.Body = body;

            mailClient.Send(message);

            return 1;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

**WEB.CONFIG CODE :**

```
    <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp from="test@gmail.com">
            <network host="relay-hosting.secureserver.net" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

What can be the problem ?

Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of your MailMessage is being identified as spam by the recipient's provider or the relay server you're using is blacklisted. If you are using `relay-hosting.secureserver.net` the later is probably the case. I would suggest using a more trusted relay provider than GoDaddy.

Comment: @lukiffer- Thanks for reply. Can you suggest other alternative for this? Which code should i write for this?

Comment: For one, I would say use a `noreply@yourdomain.com` - that way a filter is expecting an automated email. Also, you should add the required opt-out and sender identification information (U.S. requirement) to the message to avoid being filtered. If it is a blacklist issue, there are lots of other SMTP providers with good reputation. AuthSMTP is one that I've used in the past.

Comment: Oh. Ok. Thanks. Can you provide sample code for that which i can use for my problem?

Comment: This is not really a code problem beyond the content of your MailMessage. @somnath has posted additional helpful tools to identify and resolve the problem outside of code.

Comment: ya. you are right. I have used @somnath's tool. And it shows that my relay-hosting.secureserver.net is as blacklisted. What should i do?

Comment: Use another SMTP server - either one you host yourself, or a commercial provider. eg: Amazon Simple Email Service, or your hosting provider.

Answer (score 2):

Your FROM address is GMAIL.COM and you are NOT sending email from GMAIL server but from another server. Using DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM) and Sender Policy Framework (SPF) it is now possible (and most sysadmins do) specify authorized email sending servers for that domain in the domain's DNS records. This way, when a email recipient server receives an email, it can check for authenticity of the source of the email by checking the email sending server with the list of servers mentioned as authorized in the sender domain's DNS. If it does not match, then as per rules set or specified by the sender domain's sysadmin in their DNS record, the email may be outright rejected or saved as spam in the spam folder.

I guess this is what is happening. You should also check the sending server (SMTP) credentials using http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx service before sending emails.

Answer (score 2):

The email will likely show up as spam if you send from an IP address that does not have a valid SPF record for the domain you are claiming it is coming from. In this example ""relay-hosting.secureserver.net" does not have a valid IP address to act as an SMTP server for gmail.

Try doing a test sending from the actual domain you will be using in real life instead of "test@gmail.com".

If it still gets marked as spam it is very easy to add an SPF record for test@*youractualdomain.com*. Here is a site that has helped me in the past: http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch9/spf.html

Answer (score 1):

There are several things at play that conspire to raise the spam score of your email. Remember that it's not spam/notspam, but rather a "spam score" above which your email will be marked as spam by the receiving server.

I would guess that the factors at play in your case are the folowing:

- HTML body with no alternative text message
- From address does not correspond to actual server mail is sent from
- From address does not exist
- SMTP server (relay-hosting.secureserver.net) has a low reputation
- No SPF or domainKey records

The solution is in several points as well:

- Create an alternate text version of your message and include it in the body ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456346/c-sharp-send-both-html-and-text-email-most-elegant) explains how to do that)
- Use a From address that actually exists on the server the email is sent from
- Use a reputable provider for your SMTP server, such as [Sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com), [postmarkApp](http://postmarkapp.com) or [Mailjet](http://mailjet.com)
- Specifying SPF and DomainKeys DNS records allows the receiving server to identify your message as coming from the right server

Good luck!