# Properly format database data into mail message

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm in the process of trying to get the correct logic for putting data from a database into the message body of an email.
Once a week my service is going to send an email out to clients with products from brands that they might interested in. 
I'm not sure the correct way of applying the data to the email message body. I want to go with a layout like

Brand

product1
description

product2
description

etc...

I have no idea how to do this type of layout, and that brings up another question on which way to go with a text email or an html enabled email (I'm unsure if everyone now has html enabled emails).
I think using text emails then I'll run into a problem putting the data to it (because of not knowing how to insert data like that without using a string builder, or maybe I should use that and loop through the information and append it? then apply that? hmmm).

I am sure that there are many ways to do this, so I'm all ears for suggestions. I do have an option to attach the new brands and their related products in an excel sheet, but I don't really want to go with that because I think, and I may be wrong, but that's a lot of coding to format it properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a [template engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340095/can-you-recommend-a-net-template-engine) to generate the email body.

You should include both [plain text and HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456346/c-sharp-send-both-html-and-text-email-most-elegant) in the body.

Comment: I'm going to check those links out, I've never heard of a template engine before. I'm going to use a windows service to create the emails, would a template engine still work with that?